# ASP Ajax tookit html extended causing treeview SelectedNodeChanged event not to fire in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a textbox on webpage that I am using the Ajax toolkit extended to make have differnt fonts, bolds etc available to it. However this is causing a treeview node change event not to run at all in Chrome. It is fine in Firefox and was fine in Chrome a couple of weeks ago. As far as I am aware, nothing has changed in the code to stop it working, so the only thing I can think of is maybe a Chrome update has stopped it working.

My code for the ajax bit and text box are as follows. If i comment out the ajax bit, everything works.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender  ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" TargetControlID="txtQuestion" EnableSanitization="false" DisplaySourceTab="false" runat="server">
    <Toolbar>
        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
        <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
    </Toolbar>
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender >
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" Height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" autocomplete="off" runat="server" Width="490px"></asp:TextBox>
```

If anyone can help, i'd be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem with my site that uses HtmlEditorExtender. Looks like it has something to do with Chrome update. Have a look here for more details and workaround:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395318

Comment: Many thanks Przem.

The workaround "Just add attribute Text="  "  in the textbox control handled by HTMLEditorExtender" worked for me

Comment: Update: Although this work-around worked at the time. I have noticed today that it has stoped working again, although this might have been the case for a while. Taking this work-around back out fixed the issue.